# select item with filtered child items with linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-objects

I have a complicated hierarchy of elements that I would like to filter down based on a child item which is 4 deep.

Here is a sample of the classes

```
class Hotel {
    //other properties omitted for brevity 
    public List<Room> Rooms{get;set;}
}
class Room {
    //other properties omitted for brevity 
    public List<RoomType> RoomTypes{get;set;}
}
class RoomType {
    //other properties omitted for brevity 
    public List<Price> Prices {get;set;}
}
class Price {
    //other properties omitted for brevity 
    decimal TotalPrice{get;set;}
}
```

so the hotel is the top level which have some `Rooms`, which have a number of `RoomTypes` which have a number of `Prices`

I want to simply **filter out anything OTHER than the cheapest TotalPrice** and relating parents in each instance but **keep the hierarchy in place**, to leave a number of hotels with the rooms, roomtypes and minimum price

```
var filteredHotels = from hot in resp.Hotels
              let types = hot.Rooms.SelectMany(rooms => rooms.RoomTypes)
              let prices = types.SelectMany(t => t.Prices)
              select new {
                     hot
                     , types
                     , minPrice = prices.Min(p => p.TotalPrice)
              };
```

but of course that doesn't work.

in response to the comments, I require all the properties on the classes in the hierarchy. I basically just want to filter out the multiple expensive prices. and you could think a single room would have a single price, but each room can be set up differently so they have different prices. plus its not my hierarchy, its a service I am consuming..
and sorry the resp is a response from a service, which has the hotels object in it.
and thus can be ignored..

so to be clear (i hope), I need the hotels object, with a filtered list of children below it leaving me with a single cheapest TotalPrice below it..
I was hoping to avoid having to project all the properties of the hierarchy to get what I wanted but maybe it is impossible not to

thanks for any help

Comment: Why not have a `Price` property in the `Room` class. Surely a single room must have a single price?

Comment: What type is the resp object?

Comment: Please add the properties which you want in the results. It'll be easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
    var filteredHotels = resp.Hotels.Select(h =>
                            h.Rooms.Select(r =>
                            r.RoomTypes.Select(rt =>
                            new
                            {
                                HotelName = h.Name,
                                RoomName = r.Name,
                                RoomTypeName = rt.Name,
                                MinPrice = rt.Prices.Min(p => p.TotalPrice)
                            })));
```

Assuming all your classes have the Name property. You can replace that property with whatever you want.

```
class hotel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //other properties omitted for brevity 
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}
class Room
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //other properties omitted for brevity 
    public List<RoomType> RoomTypes { get; set; }
}
class RoomType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //other properties omitted for brevity 
    public List<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}
class Price
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //other properties omitted for brevity 
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
```